# JavaScript code is fine, but webpage preview is only showing my html work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an assignment for a class to create a simple web page using javascript. I've triple and quadruple checked the code, and it seems to be written perfectly; however, when I go to preview it, it only shows the heading of my page.

This is the code that I'm working on. I know it's simple, but I honestly can't figure out what's wrong with it. I would really appreciate it if someone would help me out.

```
'use strict';

var game = new Phaser.Game(1024, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'game', {preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render});

    var: background;
    var: Home1;
    var: home2;
    var: home3;
    var: home5; 
    var: home6;
    var: moose;


    var: text;
    var: textStyle;
    var: textHolder;


    function preload() {    
     game.load.image("background","HomePics/flowerhome.png");   
     game.load.image("Home1","HomePics/Home1.jpg");
     game.load.image("home2","HomePics/home2.jpg");
     game.load.image("home3","HomePics/home3.jpg");
     game.load.image("home5","HomePics/home5.jpeg");
     game.load.image("home6","HomePics/home6.jpg");
     game.load.image("moose","HomePics/icon_moose.png");    
}

function create() {     

    background = game.add.sprite(0, 0, "background");
    Home1 = game.add.sprite(200, 200, "Home1");
    home2 = game.add.sprite(200, 600, "home2");
    home3 = game.add.sprite(200, 600, "home3");
    home5 = game.add.sprite(400, 600, "home5");
    home6 = game.add.sprite(500, 375, "home6");
    moose = game.add.sprite(200, 200, "moose");    

    text = "it's waiting for you"
    textSyle = {font: "40px Roboto", fill: "#ff5d5d", align: "center"};
    textHolder = game.add.text(0,0, text, textStyle);
}

function update() { 

    moose.x = game.input.activePointer.x;
    moose.y = game.input.activePointer.y;   

}

function render() {     

}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with coding in Java? Why the Java question tag? I see only Javascript and no Java?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing this tag so as not to attract the wrong experts to your question.

Comment: What are all the `var:` labels for.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title to remove "Java".

Comment: Show the complete page. My guess is you also forgot some '<script>' tags? Did you load the "phaser" library too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://jshint.com/ to check for syntax errors when you don't want to find them by hand or, as Mr Lister mentioned, check the console in the developer tools of your browser. If the dev tools display nothing, then for some reason your code is not being executed at all.

For example, variable declarations are written without a colon so:

```
var background;
```

instead of

```
var: background;
```

You might also benefit from this [debugging guide](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and if you haven't already, please [learn to use the developer tools](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) that your browser has.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have enabled javascript in your browser or else any javascript code you write wont work!!